# jquery slider quest

Tags: jquery, slider

I have slider here. When it's 2 or more photos it's work pretty well. But when only one photo, it's still sliding itself. How to make slider not hide and show with one image?

```
  (function($){
        $.fn.MySlider = function(interval) {
            var slides;
            var cnt;
            var amount;
            var i;

            function run() {
                // hiding previous image and showing next
                $(slides[i]).fadeOut(1000);
                i++;
                if (i >= amount) i = 0;
                $(slides[i]).fadeIn(1000);

                // updating counter
                cnt.text(i+1+' / '+amount);

                // loop
                setTimeout(run, interval);
            }

            slides = $('#my_slider').children();
            cnt = $('#counter');
            amount = slides.length;
            i=0;

            // updating counter
            cnt.text(i+1+' / '+amount);

            setTimeout(run, interval);
        };
    })(jQuery);
```

Comment: You want it just to keep the one image showing, correct?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why don't you just check if amount is more than one by replacing

```
setTimeout(run, interval);
```

with

```
if (amount > 1) {
    setTimeout(run, interval);
}
```

?

Answer (score 1):

The simple answer is not to run the setTimeout portion when amount greater than 1.  Im sure there's more to this though.  Perhaps you could load it in jsFiddle

```
if(amount > 1)
setTimeout(run, interval);
```

Answer (score 1):

You should check for images count before starting slide.

change code to:

```
if (amount>1){
setTimeout(run, interval)
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Wrap the whole function in an if statement to check there are multiple images.

```
if ( $('#my_slider').children().length > 1 ){
    //run function
}
```

Answer (score 1):

What I would do is, to have a check to see if the number of images is 1 or more and based on that either run your Slider method or just bind the single image to a div element.